# Display values of properties file in jsp without using scriptlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am having a jsp with a dropdown, when the dropdown value is changed other textboxes in the jsp must be populated with the properties value based on a condition. I have achieved this by using scriptlet in my jsp. Can anyone provide me a solution to achieve the same without using scriptlet.

**JSP**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Properties"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.InputStream" %>

<%
Properties prop = new Properties();
String propFileName = "server_url.properties";

InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

if (inputStream != null) {
    prop.load(inputStream);
} else {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
}
String demoApp = prop.getProperty("DemoApps_name");
String relDashboard=prop.getProperty("RelDashBoard_name");
String demoAppLinks = prop.getProperty("DemoApps_Links");
String demoAppsdb=prop.getProperty("DemoApps_DataBase");
String demoAppservice=prop.getProperty("DemoApps_WebServices");
%>
  
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport"
 content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Monitoring Dashboard</title>

</head>
<body style="background: rgb(0, 102, 153);">

<form name="edit" method="post" action="UpdateDetails" onsubmit="return validation();">
<center>
<fieldset 
 style="border-color:white ;float: none; ">
<table class="edit" cellpadding="20" >
<tr ><td align="left" style="color: white;" >Application Name: </td><td align="left"><select id="appName" name="appName" class="dropdown" onchange="return OnSelectionChange(appName);"><option value="Application">Select Application</option><option value="Demo Application">Demo Application</option>
<option value="Reliability DashBoard">Reliability DashBoard</option></select></td></tr>

<tr><td align="left" style="color: white;" >Application Link:<font color="red">*</font> </td><td align="left"><textarea rows="4" cols="20" id="appLink" name="appLink" required ></textarea></td></tr>

<tr><td align="left" style="color: white;" >Application Database:<font color="red">*</font> </td><td align="left"><input id="appDB" name="appDB" type="text" required></td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" style="color: white;" >Application Webservices:<font color="red">*</font> </td><td align="left"><textarea rows="4" cols="20" id="appWebService" name="appWebService" required></textarea></td></tr></table>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</fieldset>
</center>
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
            function OnSelectionChange(appName) {
                var selectedOption = appName.options[appName.selectedIndex];
                var demoLink=document.getElementById('appLink');
                var demodb=document.getElementById('appDB');
                var demoWebService=document.getElementById('appWebService');
       var demoAppName='<%=demoApp%>';
                var relDashboardName='<%=relDashboard%>';
                var demoAppLinks='<%=demoAppLinks%>';
                var demoAppsdb='<%=demoAppsdb%>';
                var demoAppWebServices='<%=demoAppservice%>';
                if(selectedOption.value==demoAppName){
                    demoLink.value=demoAppLinks;
                    demodb.value=demoAppsdb;
                    demoWebService.value=demoAppWebServices;
                }
                if(selectedOption.value=='Application'){
                  demoLink.value='';
                     demodb.value='';
                     demoWebService.value='';
                    }
                
               }
        
                     
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you plz tell why do you want to avoid using scriptlet??

Comment: Using scriptlet is not a good practice, so I want to avoid it

Comment: So you want to fetch the properties file content without using scriptlet???

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to fetch the properties file values on any other Servlet and from there return all needed values like **demoApp,value1#relDashboard,value2...** like this in a String and from your JSP, in your function make an AJAX call to this servlet and you will receive the String, like as follows:

```
$.post("/path_to_the_servlet", function(data) {
    var selectedOption = appName.options[appName.selectedIndex];
    var demoLink=document.getElementById('appLink');
    var demodb=document.getElementById('appDB');
    var demoWebService=document.getElementById('appWebService');
    var param1 = data.split("#");
    for(var i=0;i<param1.length;i++) {
        var param2=param1[i].split(",");
        if(param2[0]=="demoAppName")
            var demoAppName=param2[1];
        if(param2[0]=="relDashboardName")
            var relDashboardName=param2[1];
            .
            .
            .
            //all like this
    }
});
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need need for any Ajax round this.

Comment: @AlanHay   Then can you provide me a solution without using Ajax, because I don't know Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will create a Servlet to do the IO part. 
Essentially, instead of calling your JSP directly, you call the Servlet (by mapping some URL to it - you will need to read up on how to configure this).

The Servlet then loads the information and makes it available to the JSP (via the request object) and then forward to the JSP for rendering. The JSP can use simple JSP Eexpression Language to access the properties:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String propFileName = "server_url.properties";

    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

    if (inputStream != null) {
        prop.load(inputStream);
        request.setAttribute("properties", properties);
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("myJsp.jsp").forward(request, response):


}
```

Then you can use simple EL expressions in your JSP:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var relDashboardName="${properties.getPropery('relDashboard'}"; 
            var demoAppLinks="${properties.getPropery('demoAppLinks'}"; 
         </script>
    </head>
    <body >
</html>
```